# What does this mean: "How much experience do you have gathering data for web analysis?"

Tags: meaning

I am trying to understand the following question:

```
"How much experience do you have gathering data for web analysis?"
```

I understand the concept of "web data analysis", and I understand "gathering data from the web for analysis", but the above question is not clear.

Perhaps I am being too literal or picky, but the question sounds like I would first gather data, then put it on the web, and then analyze it, which is not logical.

If you have any ideas, could you please provide a **specific** example of what kind of work would satisfy the question.

For example, maybe the question means I would download Apache Server logs from a website, import into Excel, and perform analysis?

Comment: This question belongs on a tech Q&A or SO. Recommended migration.

Comment: I'm not sure this question belongs on SO any more than it belongs here, because it is *ultimately unanswerable by anyone but the author of the original requirement*. We can only guess what he is after, but whatever our conclusion is, and no matter how logically sound it is, the author is not bound to accept it. You will still need to satisfy *his* requirements, not ours.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the wording might be a *tad* misleading. You are right, they certainly do not want you to gather data to be uploaded to the web for analysis.

I would have said, "How much experience do you have gathering web data for analysis?" The concern is analyzing web data, not analyzing data on the web.

But, the question could be rephrased as, "How much experience do you have in web analytics?" or perhaps more specifically, "How much experience do you have in *implementing* web analytics?" or, most specifically, "How much experience do you have in tagging a site to track behaviors?"

For example, at my office we use a combination of [Adobe Analytics](http://www.adobe.com/solutions/digital-analytics.html) for large clients, [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) for medium clients, [Sprout Social](http://sproutsocial.com/) for social media campaigns, and miscellaneous PHP and JavaScript to monitor and report performance.

The "gathering" part of web analytics is typically referred to as "tagging" or "tracking" a site. There are myriad methods for doing so, but almost all use a JavaScript implementation. Apache (or any) server logs can be used in this process, but for any significant site you need more data than can be offered by server logs and in a form that is more amenable to analysis.

Answer (score 0):

If you had asked this  question at stackoverflow.

"*first gather data, then put it on the web, and then analyze it, which is not logical*".

I had been a statistical programmer, where we had to design processes that gathered, pre-processed and stored data for access on the web. We wrote applications for engineers to use statistical and business tools to analyse the data.

We would be those whom management would want to ask you the question

> How much experience do you have gathering data for web analysis?

That you may not find it logical would be a concern to us if you have any idea how web-based analysis work, contrary to what you claim.

Nowadays, I work with people who gather data from moving vehicles. How would you like to gather, process and analyse information in order to interact adaptively with your source of information?

These are the least concepts you need to read up on and practice, to answer the question:

1. The industry by-phrase ELT ([Extract, load, transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load)).
2. Data architecture and database design suitable for ELT and OLAP.
3. Interfacing SAS, R or Mathlab to Java EE or .NET ASP for dynamic analysis on the web.
4. [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP)

For example, one of the crucial traits management looks  for is item 2, which involves your negotiation skills with vendors and fellow engineers to create data formats of their equipment that should include information needed by everyone in the pipeline and to track phase changes in that information. For example, how well you recognise that there are other teams needing data and how you work with them for common benefit, because the vendor, foreman, or engineer would not want to create a different format for each team.

On the other hand, if the job you are interviewing requires gathering data about the performance of the web, it entails your understanding of cookies and http. For example,

- designing cookies to make their information meaningful.
- how do you seduce/induce user behaviour to ensure you are able to have the information required.
- what information is actually helpful, what are not?
- how do you comprehend that data gathered?
- what are the issues and constraints?
- how your data turns stale, meaningless and therefore misleading?
- etc

But since you did not ask this question in stackoverflow or programmers stack, I can only give examples of what the question entails. However, had you asked this question there, those extra smart high-score people not familiar with the trade would flag your question as "too ambiguous, unhelpful, inviting controversy".